# strtokの返り値をstrcpyするとSegfaultするのはなぜですか

Tags: c

C言語で、文字列を空白で区切り、数字の配列で返す以下のような関数を書きました。しかし、この書き方だとSegmentation faultしてしまいます。なぜでしょう?

```
void putupNums(char* str, int* result) {
  char buff[80];
  int i = 0;
  strcpy(buff, strtok(str, " "));
  for(i = 0; (i < 2) && (buff != NULL); ++i) {
    result[i] = atoi(buff);
    strcpy(buff, strtok(NULL, " "));
  }
}
```

buffをポインタ変数にし、strtokから代入するようにすれば問題は解決するのですが、この実装でどうして動作しないのでしょうか。

Comment: `buff != NULL` : `buff`は配列で固定のアドレスを持つので決してNULLにはなりません。 よって`strcpy(buff, NULL);`を除外できていません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「ポインタ変数への代入」と「配列変数へのstrcpy」を混同されているようです。両者ではプログラムの意味が全く変わってしまいます。

> buffをポインタ変数にし、strtokから代入するようにすれば問題は解決する

おっしゃる通り、下記コードならば期待通り動作します。

```
void putupNums(char* str, int* result) {
  char *buff;
  int i = 0;
  buff = strtok(str, " ");
  for(i = 0; (i < 2) && (buff != NULL); ++i) {
    result[i] = atoi(buff);
    buff = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
}
```

ポインタ変数への代入は、`strtok`関数が返してくるポインタ値をそのまま格納します。`NULL`ポインタもそのまま格納できます。

```
char *buff;
buff = strtok(str, " ");
```

一方の配列変数へのstrcpyでは、`strtok`関数が返したポインタが指しているデータを、文字列とみなして配列`buff`にコピーする動作になります。`NULL`ポインタが返された場合、`strcpy`関数内部では「ヌルポインタが指している文字列」にアクセスしようとして、Segmentation faultとなります。

```
char buff[80];
strcpy(buff, strtok(str, " "));
```

Answer (score 3):

`strtok`はトークンがなくなったとき`NULL`を返します。
Segfaultが起きるのは、`NULL`を`strcpy`でコピーしているからです。

`buff`に`strtok`の戻り値を代入した場合、`strtok`が`NULL`を返した時に`buff != NULL`が偽になりループを抜けるため`strcpy`は実行されません。